# How to register Buildbot worker with master?

Tags: buildbot

I had to replace a Buildbot master server, and even though I seemingly reinstalled it with the identical code and settings as before, I must have missed something, because it's now rejecting all requests from all existing workers with errors in its `twistd.log` file like:

```
2018-08-22 21:17:28-0400 [Broker,678,10.229.39.202] invalid login from unknown user 'worker2'
2018-08-22 21:17:28-0400 [Broker,678,10.229.39.202] Peer will receive following PB traceback:
2018-08-22 21:17:28-0400 [Broker,678,10.229.39.202] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: twisted.cred.error.UnauthorizedLogin:
```

How do I re-register the workers with master? [The docs](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/installation/worker.html) don't mention this, nor where the worker username/passwords are stored. I tried re-running the `buildbot-worker create-worker ...` commands and then restarting Buildbot, but that had no effect.

Comment: After diggin in buildbot, I found out that the error is because the worker is not configured correctly on the master side. You need to have matching name and password for that worker

Answer (score 2):

Goog day.
In a worker name/pass stored in a **buildbot.tac**

Name/pass in a worker must be same as in **master.cfg** file at master.

For example, if **master.cfg** on master contain

```
 c['workers'].append(worker.Worker('remote-worker', 'pass'))
```

a **buildbot.tac** at worker should contain

```
...
workername='remote-worker'
passwd='pass'
...
```

Please, note, that if you make a changes in a **master.cfg** you should upgrade master via command `buildbot upgrade-master`:
http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/installation/buildmaster.html

> The upgrade-master command is idempotent. It is safe to run it
>   multiple times. After each upgrade of the buildbot code, you should
>   use upgrade-master on all your buildmasters.

P.S.
On 3rd September buildbot team presented new version 1.4 I have buildbot master 1.3 and one buildbot worker 1.4 and it work correctly